# How to setup DNS to connect 2 servers with 1 Domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-zone, a-record

I have 2 Servers:

```
Server 1 IPs: 
45.35.56.194
45.35.56.195

Server 2 IPs:
173.254.214.217
173.254.214.218
```

Each server has different clients, therefore, Server 1 client has nothing to do with Server 2 clients.

To my Server 1 clients I gave these Name Servers:

```
ns1.resourcesofnet.net - 45.35.56.194
ns1.resourcesofnet.net - 45.35.56.195
```

To my Server 2 clients I gave these Name Servers:

```
ns3.resourcesofnet.net - 173.254.214.217
ns4.resourcesofnet.net - 173.254.214.218
```

In my domain registrar, I have created 4 child Name Servers.

```
ns1.resourcesofnet.net - 45.35.56.194
ns2.resourcesofnet.net - 45.35.56.195
ns3.resourcesofnet.net - 173.254.214.217
ns4.resourcesofnet.net - 173.254.214.218
```

On my both servers I created a vhost for resourcesofnet.net and added A records accordingly.

Now the problem is, it's been many days, my DNS still randomly stops resolving for some domains.

Server 1 Example site:

```
www.unique-links.com.pk
```

Server 2 Example Site:

```
al-quba.com
```

Can anyone please check why is it happening? Has it got anything to do with configuration of DNS on both Servers?

Here is [DNS report](http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=resourcesofnet.net).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This looks very like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Could you tell us what you are *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: @MadHatter actually, we have half clients on Server 1 and half on Server 2. To Server 1 clients, we gave ns1 and ns2 and to Server 2 clients, we gave ns3 and ns4 of the same domain name. The problem we are facing right now is that DNS doesn't resolve properly. Sometimes, some clients report their sites dont work. WhatsMyDNS also shows cross among a few regisions.

Comment: **Show** us your underlying problem.  Give us examples.  I *very strongly* suspect that the problem is not what you think it is.  Note also that cpanel questions are off-topic for ServerFault, so if it turns out any of this is cpanel-related, the question might well be closed.

Comment: @MadHatter yes, I think I did not explain it properly. Let me revise my question and current scenario, then it might be easy for you to understand.

Comment: @MadHatter I have updated the question. Please check. If there is still issue in understanding, please let me know  I can explain more. Thanks a lot for your time. Really appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, you're completely missing my point.  You said earlier that your actual problem was that clients resolving off some of your NSes didn't resolve some domains correctly.  I asked you to show us that.  Instead, you're still focussing on your personal solution.  You've also redacted the domain names, which renders the question nearly impossible to answer.  I recommend you read [this meta answer](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/6574/55514), then do as I asked and **show us the actual problem you are having**.  Until then, I don't think this question can be answered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49773/discussion-between-raja-amer-khan-and-madhatter).

Comment: @MadHatter I have added the actual domain and server IPs here. Please check. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this.

Child Name Servers is the correct way to achieve this functionality. I was just missing one thing.

Once child Name Servers are created on domain registrar. We have to add A records for NS3 and NS4 on Server 1 and similarly A records for NS1 and NS2 on Server 2.

So these A records must exist in DNS entries of both servers:

```
ns1.resourcesofnet.net - 45.35.56.194
ns2.resourcesofnet.net - 45.35.56.195
ns3.resourcesofnet.net - 173.254.214.217
ns4.resourcesofnet.net - 173.254.214.218
```